# Calculate stars from grades(5-1 and 1-5)

Tags: php, math

I have grades from 1 to 5 where 1 is the best and 5 is the worst(But not just integral numbers like 1, also 1.14 and so on). 
I want to calculate how many stars each grade would be(5 stars would be the best, 1 star the worst - 3 would stay 3 of course - but the rest?) 
I googled to get the result but I'm not finding anything helpful. Maybe I'm missing the forest for the trees, I don't know. Basically it would be the reverse number I guess?
I want to do that in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straightforward I would think:

```
$new_grade = 6 - $old_grade;
```

Or for a more generic solution:

```
$new_grade = $grade_max + $grade_min - $old_grade;
```

Answer (score 1):

Star = 6 - Grade

So:

```
5 → 1  
4 → 2  
3 → 3  
2 → 4   
1 → 5
```